# gnome-keyring-daemon warnings

Tags: plasma5, gnome-keyring

I am using gnome-keyring with my KDE Plasma (Arch Linux). I modified:

```
/etc/pam.d/login

auth       required     pam_securetty.so
auth       requisite    pam_nologin.so
auth       include      system-local-login
auth       optional     pam_gnome_keyring.so
account    include      system-local-login
session    include      system-local-login
session    optional     pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

and also:

```
/etc/pam.d/passwd

#password   required    pam_cracklib.so difok=2 minlen=8 dcredit=2 ocredit=2 retry=3
#password   required    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow use_authtok
password    required    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok
password    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

and added to my .xintrc (I start plasma with startx, multi-user.target as default).

```
eval $(/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11,secrets)
```

It works, but my journal is floated with warnings:

```
lis 11 16:57:47 maciexhome gnome-keyring-daemon[815]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/10, but it's already registered
lis 11 16:57:52 maciexhome gnome-keyring-daemon[815]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/10, but it's already registered
lis 11 16:57:53 maciexhome gnome-keyring-daemon[815]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/10, but it's already registered
lis 11 16:57:57 maciexhome gnome-keyring-daemon[815]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/10, but it's already registered
```

Is this something I should be worried about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running NextCloud, then there is a [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1776751) for the spammy log messages you describe. I am getting them on my Fedora 29 Cinnamon desktop too. With nextcloud-client-2.6.1-1.fc29.x86_64.

It looks like it is fixed upstream at Nextcloud (as of 7th Dec 2019), so we that are using Fedora are just waiting for the packaging to be released.

Apparently v2.6.0 of the client does not exhibit the behaviour. And they are confirming that v2.6.2 has the fix.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm using nextclouddesktop-client. I will wait for the 2.6.2 then.